# How to display a month in VBA given conditions

Tags: vba, excel

Currently I am trying to display a month given certain conditions in VBA. I have two columns named Quarter and Exact Month in Quarter. Based upon these two conditions, I would like to display a month.

For example, For Quarter 1 Month 1, I would like the new column to display January.

Thank you for your help.

[image: Desired outcome]

Comment: Just to clarify, e.g. would Quarter 3 Month 3 be September? Do the columns have just the quarter number and month number, or the text Quarter <n> Month<n>? A screen shot of the desired output would help.

Comment: Why is Quarter needed at all if you have month number?  You just need the name of the month, or a full calendar?  Can you please show what you have and what you need?  A worksheet function would be easiest but if you need it to be done in VBA for some reason (homework, I'd assume) then please show what you have so far.

Comment: Please edit your question and post what you have tried so far. the solution is quite trivial, once you start writing im sure you can solve it.

Comment: Yes exactly. I will post a screenshot shortly

Comment: side note: you dont even need vba for that, it can be done with a formula

Answer (score 0):

You can just offset each quarter by a value of **3**. For instance, Q2 will correspond with 3. When you add your quarter serial #,  it will be converted into a calendar serial # (1-12). After that, you just need to set the desired format.

This will just be an excel solution, and if this needs to be in VBA, you can apply similar logic there.

You can do this a few ways. The below image just serves as an example. How to apply this will depend on your data structure. You may need to implement a `VLOOKUP` as such.

> G2 = TEXT(Date(2018, E2 + VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$B:$5,2,0),"MMM")

[image]

Comment: The month's long form - e.g. "January" is received by the `MMMM` `TEXT` argument instead of the triple variant getting "Jan" only :-)

Answer (score 0):

**[1] Only one Excel Formula in Column C - doesn't need any helper columns:**

This example e.g. for cell C2 as shown in your post **converts** quarters * 3 months (1 quarter = 3 months) minus 1 plus month in quarter to **DATE** (argument year can be any year >= 1900)  and displays the month's Long form via **TEXT argument `MMMM`**; quarter values are extracted from the last string position in column A ( here A2) via RIGHT:

`=TEXT(DATE(1900,3*(RIGHT($A2,1)-1)+$B2,1),"MMMM")`

**[2] Approach via VBA Example Function**

Uses the same logic as above:

```
Sub Test()
    MsgBox getMonthInQuarter("Quarter 4", 3)
End Sub

Function getMonthInQuarter(ByVal quarter As Variant, ByVal month As Integer) As String
Const MonthsInQuarter As Integer = 3
Dim q As Integer: q = Val(Right(quarter, 1))
' Return function value
  getMonthInQuarter = Format(DateSerial(1900, MonthsInQuarter * (q - 1) + month, 1), "MMMM")
End Function
```